# MobileFirst: Mobile Web - Page refresh to keep session alive

Tags: session-state, mobile-website, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a MobileFirst based Mobile-Web app using Angularjs. In case, a user **refreshes the page** then **all files get reloaded again** as per standard browser behavior. This causes the **user session invalid**, how should we handle this ? disabling the refresh button is not good option.

**Environment:**

- MobileFirst v7.0
- Angularjs 1.4.3
- any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mobile Web environment has support for cache manifest, which allows caching files so that even though you reload/refresh the web app it will know to not reload all resources from the server. You can attempt implementing it to see if it alleviates your issue.

See more here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_appcache_procedure.html?lang=en